# want to run multiple consumers on same RabbitMQ queue

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue

I have an application with RabbitMQ at the backend. So I want to develop custom 3rd party analysis code which it connects application queues on RabbitMQ and collect data. So my issue is I want to be sure both application and my code do not lose any data from rabbitmq.

If it is possible how can I configure RabbitMQ queues? I have administrative access on RabbitMQ. 
I hope it's not code of producer issue because I don't have access the application code

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

**Change the current exchange/queue mapping to allow for message replication**

At the moment we can simplify that existing producer sends a message to existing exchange, that routes the message to some queue, from which the messages are now consumed:

```
[producer-app] ---> existing-exchange ---> existing-queue ---> [existing-consumer]
```

Now, what you want to have a following design, with new consumer consuming the same messages:

```
[producer-app] ---> existing-exchange ---> existing-queue ---> [existing-consumer]
                                      \--> new-queue --------> [your-consumer]
```

You might need to change configuration of `existing-exchange` to allow replication of your message - for example `direct` and `fanout` will create the same message on each of the queues.

Depending on your application it might be quite easy to perform without changes in producer, but you need to be aware of possible pitfalls:

- producer might re-declare exchanges/queues/bindings from time to time, and throw exceptions if the current state cannot be change to its request (this might happen if you change exchange's type)
- you need to manage the `new-queue` on your own (preferably from your consumer artifact), as it is going to receive all the messages; in case your consumer shuts down, the queue is not going to disappear unless it is made exclusive or has TTL set

Comment: Hello Adam
Do you have any configuration example for your ascii art based recommendation. I could not get long downtime for this environment so I have to apply correct solution in short window